Is there a link in theme, between Lev.16.8-22; with Rev.12; concerning the scape goat ceremony, and the cleansing of the sanctuary?
When reading Rev 12 concerning the woman that is taken to the wilderness and the man child that is caught up; I am reminded of the scape goat ceremony, in how a sacrifice is received, and one goat is sent out to the wilderness.
I also have learned of the how the atonement is concerned with objects, and the sanctuary, before the LORD would appear.
This brings me to the similar times periods, and themes found in the book of Daniel with the cleansing of the sanctuary (Dan. 8.14), with the book of Revelation (cp. Rev. 11.2); and the appearing of the Son of Man (1.7).
And the statement "Then answered all the people, and said, His blood be on us, and on our children" (Mt.27.25);
as if the man child is caught up, and the woman with the sin on it is sent out to the wilderness, for the cleansing of God's sacred space within Israel, resulting in the restoration of the Nation of Israel, and God's sovereignty over creation, through His corporate conquering image.
So does Rev 12 contain the prophetic fulfillment of the day of atonement, and the scape goat theme, and if so what is its significance?

Apart from the single word (not enough) "wilderness" I cannot see any other connection here.

@Thatwemay - There is a connection but it is not fulfilled. The fulfillment comes at the final judgement when the serpent is not thrown to the earth, but into the lake of fire (Rev 20:10), which is symbolized by the dead sea where the Israelites would push the scapegoat over the cliffs of Azazel. The dead sea wilderness is also where Jesus went to be tempted by the serpent, which is the burial place of Israel's sins. He is literally getting victory for all of Israel's sins.

Why don't you write an answer,  I would like to learn more of this view. There seems to be an inversion, where the flood is swallowed up, and a clear connection with the cleansing of the sanctuary link in Daniel, with the corresponding prophecy of Revelation

Spoiler alert - there is no literary nor theological connection between Lev 16 (the day of atonement) and Rev 12 (the woman, the dragon and the wilderness).  Indeed, they appear to be antithetical as will now be shown.



Feature
Leviticus 16, Day of Atonement
Revelation 12, Woman, Child, Dragon




Players
Two goats, "the Lord's goat" and "Azazel" = Scapegoat; High Priest
The Woman, The Dragon, The Child caught up to God, Michael


Preparatory
Sin offering of young bull for High Priest
Woman pregnant, Dragon sweeps one third of stars of heaven and threatens woman


Distinction
Two identical goats distinguished by lot
All players are already very different (ie, no lots)


Main event
Lord's goat sacrificed; Scapegoat lead out to the desert unharmed
Woman gives birth to a child who rules with iron scepter and caught up to God; Woman flees to desert for 1260 days as protection from the dragon


Result
Sanctuary cleansed
Dragon pursues the woman to persecute her in the desert for Time, times, and half a time; dragon spews river of water but earth swallows river of water, dragon enraged and prepares for war



In short, I see no connections between these passages.

The symbolism of the day of atonement has been fulfilled already. The scene from Jesus' trial, where Pilate presented the Messiah and Barabbas (also called Jesus Barabbas in some manuscripts), to the crowd hyperlinks to Leviticus 16.

15 Now on the occasion of the feast the governor was accustomed to
release to the crowd one prisoner whom they wished. 16 And at that
time they had a notorious prisoner called [Jesus] Barabbas. 17 So when
they had assembled, Pilate said to them, “Which one do you want me to
release to you, [Jesus] Barabbas, or Jesus called Messiah?” 18 For he
knew that it was out of envy that they had handed him over. 19 While
he was still seated on the bench, his wife sent him a message, “Have
nothing to do with that righteous man. I suffered much in a dream
today because of him.” 20 The chief priests and the elders persuaded
the crowds to ask for Barabbas but to destroy Jesus. 21 The governor
said to them in reply, “Which of the two do you want me to release to
you?” They answered, “Barabbas!” 22 Pilate said to them, “Then what
shall I do with Jesus called Messiah?” They all said, “Let him be
crucified!” 23 But he said, “Why? What evil has he done?” They only
shouted the louder, “Let him be crucified!” 24 When Pilate saw that he
was not succeeding at all, but that a riot was breaking out instead,
he took water and washed his hands in the sight of the crowd, saying,
“I am innocent of this man’s blood. Look to it yourselves.” 25 And the
whole people said in reply, “His blood be upon us and upon our
children.” 26 Then he released Barabbas to them, but after he had
Jesus scourged, he handed him over to be crucified. (Matthew 27)

The Letter of Hebrews presents Christ's atoning sacrifice as once for all fulfilment of Yom Kippur.

1 Now [even] the first covenant had regulations for worship and an
earthly sanctuary. 2 For a tabernacle was constructed, the outer one,
in which were the lampstand, the table, and the bread of offering;
this is called the Holy Place. 3 Behind the second veil was the
tabernacle called the Holy of Holies, 4 in which were the gold altar
of incense and the ark of the covenant entirely covered with gold. In
it were the gold jar containing the manna, the staff of Aaron that had
sprouted, and the tablets of the covenant. 5 Above it were the
cherubim of glory overshadowing the place of expiation. Now is not the
time to speak of these in detail. 6 With these arrangements for
worship, the priests, in performing their service, go into the outer
tabernacle repeatedly, 7 but the high priest alone goes into the inner
one once a year, not without blood that he offers for himself and for
the sins of the people. 8 In this way the holy Spirit shows that the
way into the sanctuary had not yet been revealed while the outer
tabernacle still had its place. 9 This is a symbol of the present
time, in which gifts and sacrifices are offered that cannot perfect
the worshiper in conscience 10 but only in matters of food and drink
and various ritual washings: regulations concerning the flesh, imposed
until the time of the new order. 11 But when Christ came as high
priest of the good things that have come to be, passing through the
greater and more perfect tabernacle not made by hands, that is, not
belonging to this creation, 12 he entered once for all into the
sanctuary, not with the blood of goats and calves but with his own
blood, thus obtaining eternal redemption. 13 For if the blood of goats
and bulls and the sprinkling of a heifer’s ashes can sanctify those
who are defiled so that their flesh is cleansed, 14 how much more will
the blood of Christ, who through the eternal spirit offered himself
unblemished to God, cleanse our consciences from dead works to worship
the living God. 15 For this reason he is mediator of a new covenant:
since a death has taken place for deliverance from transgressions
under the first covenant, those who are called may receive the
promised eternal inheritance. 16 Now where there is a will, the death
of the testator must be established. 17 For a will takes effect only
at death; it has no force while the testator is alive. 18 Thus not
even the first covenant was inaugurated without blood. 19 When every
commandment had been proclaimed by Moses to all the people according
to the law, he took the blood of calves [and goats], together with
water and crimson wool and hyssop, and sprinkled both the book itself
and all the people, 20 saying, “This is ‘the blood of the covenant
which God has enjoined upon you.’” 21 In the same way, he sprinkled
also the tabernacle and all the vessels of worship with blood. 22
According to the law almost everything is purified by blood, and
without the shedding of blood there is no forgiveness. 23 Therefore,
it was necessary for the copies of the heavenly things to be purified
by these rites, but the heavenly things themselves by better
sacrifices than these. 24 For Christ did not enter into a sanctuary
made by hands, a copy of the true one, but heaven itself, that he
might now appear before God on our behalf. 25 Not that he might offer
himself repeatedly, as the high priest enters each year into the
sanctuary with blood that is not his own; 26 if that were so, he would
have had to suffer repeatedly from the foundation of the world. But
now once for all he has appeared at the end of the ages to take away
sin by his sacrifice. 27 Just as it is appointed that human beings die
once, and after this the judgment, 28 so also Christ, offered once to
take away the sins of many, will appear a second time, not to take
away sin but to bring salvation to those who eagerly await him.
(Hebrews 9)

Obviously, Jesus fulfilled the roles of both goats of the day of atonement. And Barabbas' part was just to help people understand what was happening in front of their eyes. John the Baptist calling Christ: “the Lamb of God, who takes away the sin of the world”, merges symbolism of the paschal lamb and the scapegoat.
The motives used in Revelation 12 hyperlink to the wanderings of Israel in the desert and Elijah's escape to the wilderness.

The wilderness theme in Revelation ch12 is an echo of the Exodus from Egypt, being another flight from a hostile power.
One point of contact is the fact that Pharaoh is described as "the greeat dragon that lies in the middle of his streams" (Ezekiel ch29 v3).
In v14, the two wings of the great eagle have been inspired by the words of the Lord at Sinai; "You have seen what I did to the Egyptians, and how I lifted you up on eagles' wings and brought you to myself" (Exodus ch19 v4).
v15. For the serpent trying to sweep away the woman with a flood, compare "Egypt rises like th Nile, whose waters surge. He saai, I will rise, I will cover the earth, i will destroy cities and their inhabitants" 9Jeremiah ch46 v8).
v16 For the earth swallowing the river, compare "Thou dist stretch out thy right hand, the earth swallowed them" (Exodus ch15 v12).
The final similarity is the successful escape into the wilderness, where the people will be "nourished" by their God.
